# Success delete the data from the database, but it won't update until close the form and run it again

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I already could delete the data from the database through form and I used the AutoCompleteStringCollection to search the StudentID from the database, but when it successfully deleted, the AutoCompleteStringCollection which refer to the StudentID, won't updated until I close the form and run it again.

Here is the code that I am using for deletion and AutoCompleteStringCollection:

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection _collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

private void DeleteStudent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Collection(sender, e);
        }

private void Collection(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT DISTINCT [StudentID] FROM [Student] ORDER BY [StudentID] ASC";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dReader.Read())
                    {
                        string _studentID = dReader["StudentID"].ToString();
                        _collection.Add(_studentID);
                    }

                    dReader.Close();
                }

                this.textBox9.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                this.textBox9.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                this.textBox9.AutoCompleteCustomSource = _collection;

                conn.Close();
            }
        }

private void Deleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string commandUpdate = "DELETE FROM [Student] WHERE [StudentID] = @StudentID";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandUpdate, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@StudentID"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                _wait.ShowDialog();

                System.Media.SoundPlayer _sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                _sounds.Play();

                DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully!", "Deleted");

                if (_dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    button2_Click(sender, e);
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Here is the image:

I. In the below image, you can see that the AutoCompleteStringCollection shows the "TP395134" StudentID.

[image]

II. In the below image, you can see that the database stored "TP395134" StudentID.

[image]

III. When I am delete the "TP395134" StudentID from the database through the form, there is no data in the database number 2. But the AutoCompleteStringCollection still shows the "TP395134" like number 1, even though I already deleted it and the AutoCompleteStringCollection won't update until the form closed.

***Question: How can I update the AutoCompleteStringCollection when I successfully delete a correspondent StudentID without have to close the form and open it again?***

Your answer much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After deleting the record for the database just [remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletestringcollection.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it from your collection

```
_collection.Remove(this.textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute your Collection() method in the delete method...